# "Warning: Simulation will start at a nonzero initial time" how could i fix this error?

Tags: matlab, plot, discrete-mathematics

This is my code my how could I avoid "Warning: Simulation will start at a nonzero initial time."?

```
A=[1]
B=[0.12]
C=[1]
D=[0]
u=[-0.0137 -0.012 -0.009 -0.005 -0.003 -0.003 0.001];
x0 = 0.9914;
Ts=1;
sistema=ss(A,B,C,D,Ts)
t=[2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019];    
y=lsim(sistema,u,t,x0);
plot(t,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are simulating a time-invariant system, you can simply shift your time vector to start from zero when calling the `lsim` command. The resulting vector `y` will be the same in both cases, but the shifted case won't have the warning:

```
>> y = lsim(sistema,u,t,x0)
Warning: Simulation will start at a nonzero initial time. 
y =
  0.9914
  0.9898
  0.9883
  0.9872
  0.9866
  0.9863
  0.9859

>> y = lsim(sistema,u,t-t(1),x0)
y =
  0.9914
  0.9898
  0.9883
  0.9872
  0.9866
  0.9863
  0.9859
```

Answer (score 0):

How @Kavka suggested is also how I would fix the warning; however, you could return that warning off using `warning` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html#d118e1583587). Use  `lastwarn` to get the warning